# Where to learn more on variational calculus?

Tags: reference-request, calculus-of-variations

I'm interested learning more on variational calculus, I found it useful in addressing some PDE-related problems, but I never had a formal course on it.

There are people who think it is appropriate to merely suggest reading a book, but obviously if people magically learned everything by picking up a book, universities and professors would never have existed, we would only ever have libraries and nothing more, so such responses are off-topic unless they are more constructively integrated into a holistic solution.

Simple web series are too colloquial, but research papers are too hastily technical without explaining the context and steps. I see there is room in the middle between these, but I have not seen any particular organization take the steps in creating it so far.

Comment: Based on your criteria, I am having difficulty imagining what an answer to your question would look like. I think that "merely reading a book" would not help very much, as you say, but if the book has exercises in it, and you attempt a good number of those, maybe dropping by this site to ask for help or hints on some of the exercises in there, I don't see why you wouldn't have a good learning experience. Is there something I am missing, or can you give us an idea of what an answer to your question might look like?

Comment: I would say if there was an organized course-like structure with a combination of a book, videos and specific exercises, that would likely be enough. Like I said, a solution should be holistic if it is going to have a realistic chance of addressing a topic, the former generations of math and science were intentionally construed to be difficult to obscure information to the public, which is not an exaggeration, elitism was and still is rampant and authors don't realize that. The fact that a calculus-of-variations tag even exists here means I'm not the first one to ask about it.

Comment: I guess my main suggestion is then to try what you have done in the past. Or else otherwise, I think that a good many people "can get by" reading a good book on the topic and trying the exercises for themselves. It can be very helpful to talk to other people who can help you (even if it's just on this site) about what you are reading if you get stuck. That in mind, if you ask people on this site to recommend you a suitable book for self-study, I think you would have good luck finding a nice selection of options.